# Unmarshalling using castor mapping

Tags: mapping, unmarshalling, castor

I have a doubt in using castor mapping.
I know Castor will look for classes with the same name as that of element name. I have my castor mapping ready and it is working fine.
My doubt is, what if an element is received as null [I mean no value is being passed]? Castor will try to instantiate the class and assign null? or will it skip those classes?
If it tries to create an instance of that class, what performance are we going to loose? something to discard or does it have much impact on performance?

EDIT-Including the XML

```
<Order>
        <Activity>
            <ActivityID>String</ActivityID>
            <ActivityName>String</ActivityName>
            <CurrentActivityInd>String</CurrentActivityInd>
            <Description>String</Description>
            <Reason>String</Reason>
            <StartDateTime>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</StartDateTime>
            <EndDateTime>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</EndDateTime>
            <Status>String</Status>
            <Action>String</Action>
            <Owner>String</Owner>
        </Activity>   </Order>
```

Above is just a part of my XML. "Order can have any number of activity child within it".My question is, 
What if I pass the XML like  without any value? Will it instantiate Order and Activity class or Order class alone or none of the two?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put an extract of the xml explaining better your case. It can be different behaviour according your datatype (e.g primitive or Object; element present but empty or no element).